# Дефрагментация MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

можно ли сделать так чтоб при дефрагментации базы MySQL временная таблица создавалась на другом диске (или другой директории), а не там где лежит таблица которая будет дефрагментироватся? Заранее спасибо )

Comment: А что такое "дефрагментация базы" ? Если вы про optimize table - то нельзя, никакой "временной" таблицы не создается. Создается файл под новую таблицу, в нее переносятся данные и вот этот новый файл становится рабочей таблицей

Comment: Так а можно сделать так чтоб этот файл создавался на другом диске ? Так как этот файл весит столько же сколько и база для которой делается optimize table. И если база весит где-то 500GB то нужен уже 1ТБ физического диска.........

Comment: Если файл будет создан на другом диске то как после оптимизации попадет обратно на первый ? И ответ в общем то: файл невозможно создавать на другом диске. А вот на счет "1 ТБ физического диска" я бы поспорил. Создавайте базу на логическом томе вроде lvm

Comment: Ну как вариант я бы попроовал остановив MySQL перенести оригинальную таблицу на другой диск, сделать символическую ссылку из основного каталога (проверено, MySQL такие таблицы нормально цепляет). И потом выполнял бы optimize. Но вот этот момент надо проверять на небольшой тестовой таблице. 100% уверенности что MySQL правильно отработает переименование в таком случае у меня нет

Comment: P.S. У вас такие большие таблицы в myisam ? P.P.S Какой смысл в optimize если после него ожидается получить так же 500 Gb ?